# Extracting specific value from large string SQL

Tags: sql, json, string, t-sql, varchar

I've used a combination of CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING but can't get it working.

I get passed a variable in SQL that contains a lot of text but has an email in it. I need to extract the email value.

I have to use SQL 2008.

I'm trying to extract the value between **"EmailAddress":"** and **",**

An example string is here:

```
{  "Type":test,
   "Admin":test,
   "User":{
      "UserID":"16959191",
      "FirstName":"Test",
      "Surname":"Testa",
      "EmailAddress":"Test.Test@test.com",
      "Address":"Test"
}
}
```

Comment: Why not use built-in JSON functionality?

Comment: [JSON data in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2017, then use `OPENJSON`, if not, you may well want to look at alternative options outside of SQL Server; its string manipulation powers aren't great.

Comment: I'm unfortunately working with SQL 2008 - I have no choice in this.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 is compeltely unsupported, and has been for almost a year now. I would add JSON support as just another reason to get that upgrade implemented sooner rather than later. If you *are* using unsupported software, you should really be telling us that in the question when you ask, @Sam . Users will normally assume that you are *at least* using supported technology, or possibly the latest without details of the version. But, like I mentioned, if you are using 2008, I suggest using something *else* to read JSON data. 2008 does not support JSON.

Comment: Okay, will do. Many thanks.

Comment: `SELECT SUBSTRING(@json, CHARINDEX('"EmailAddress":', @json) + LEN('"EmailAddress":') + 1, CHARINDEX('",', @json, CHARINDEX('"EmailAddress":', @json)) - (CHARINDEX('"EmailAddress":', @json) + LEN('"EmailAddress":')) - 1)`. It's simplicity itself! Dealing with the fallout when this falls flat on its face if the string itself contains escape sequences or just extra whitespace is left as an exercise to the reader. This cannot be made reliable under all possible legal JSON inputs without a ton of (inefficient) work, so doing this at the client side is greatly preferred.

Comment: This is not valid JSON, probably just a typo while setting up a sample: `"Type":test` is missing the quotes around `test`...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't upgrade to 2016 or higher, you can use a combination of `substring` and `charindex`.
I've used a common table expression to make it less cumbersome, but you don't have to.

```
DECLARE @json varchar(4000) = '{  "Type":test,
   "Admin":test,
   "User":{
      "UserID":"16959191",
      "FirstName":"Test",
      "Surname":"Testa",
      "EmailAddress":"Test.Test@test.com",
      "Address":"Test"
}
}';

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT @Json as Json,
    CHARINDEX('"EmailAddress":', @json) + LEN('"EmailAddress":') As StartIndex
)

SELECT SUBSTRING(Json, StartIndex, CHARINDEX(',', json, StartIndex) - StartIndex)
FROM CTE
```

Result: `"Test.Test@test.com"`

Answer (score 1):

The first hint is: Move to v2016 if possible to use JSON support natively. v2008 is absolutely outdated...

The second hint is: Any string action (and all my approaches below will need some string actions too), will suffer from forbidden characters, unexpected blanks or any other surprise you might find within your data.

Try it like this:

First I create a *mockup scenario* to simulate your issue

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourJson NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (N'{  "Type":"test1",
   "Admin":"test1",
   "User":{
      "UserID":"16959191",
      "FirstName":"Test1",
      "Surname":"Test1a",
      "EmailAddress":"Test1.Test1@test.com",
      "Address":"Test1"
      }
}')
,(N'{  "Type":"test2",
   "Admin":"test2",
   "User":{
      "UserID":"16959191",
      "FirstName":"Test2",
      "Surname":"Test2a",
      "EmailAddress":"Test2.Test2@test.com",
      "Address":"Test2"
      }
}');
```

--Starting with v2016 there is JSON support

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(t.YourJson, '$.User.EmailAddress')
FROM @tbl t
```

--String-methods
--use CHARINDEX AND SUBSTRING

```
DECLARE @FirstBorder NVARCHAR(MAX)='"EMailAddress":';
DECLARE @SecondBorder NVARCHAR(MAX)='",';

SELECT t.*
      ,A.Pos1
      ,B.Pos2
      ,SUBSTRING(t.YourJson,A.Pos1,B.Pos2 - A.Pos1) AS ExtractedEMail
FROM @tbl t
OUTER APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX(@FirstBorder,t.YourJson)+LEN(@FirstBorder)) A(Pos1)
OUTER APPLY(SELECT CHARINDEX(@SecondBorder,t.YourJson,A.Pos1)) B(Pos2);
```

--use a XML trick

```
SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE((SELECT t.YourJson AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')),'"EmailAddress":','<mailAddress value='),',',' />') + '</x>' AS XML)
      .value('(/x/mailAddress/@value)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @tbl t
```

Some explanations:

- JSON-support will parse the value directly from a JSON path.
- For CHARINDEX AND SUBSTRING I use `APPLY`. The advantage is, that you can use the computed positions like a variable. No need to repeat the CHARINDEX statements over and over.
- The XML approach will transform your JSON to a rather strange and ugly XML. The only sensefull element is `<mailAddress>` with an attribute `value`. We can use the native XML method `.value()` to retrieve the value you are asking for:

An intermediate XML looks like this:

```
<x>{  "Type":"test1" /&gt;
       "Admin":"test1" /&gt;
       "User":{
          "UserID":"16959191" /&gt;
          "FirstName":"Test1" /&gt;
          "Surname":"Test1a" /&gt;
          <mailAddress value="Test1.Test1@test.com" />
          "Address":"Test1"
          }
    }</x>
```